# FirebaseMessagingService delay happens after using for a while

Tags: android, firebase, chat, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello I am trying to write a chat application.

I am using Firebase Cloud messaging

The server side code:

```
    Sender sender = new NotificationService(serverKey);
    Message message = new Message.Builder()
            .collapseKey("message")
            .timeToLive(500)
            .delayWhileIdle(false)
            .priority(Message.Priority.HIGH)
            .addData("message"+currentSendingRequestTimeInMillis, typeOfMessage+" Time Request"+currentSendingRequestTimeInMillis)
            .build();
        MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, all, 1);
```

Code on Android side:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    try {
        boolean found=false;

        Set<String> keySet = remoteMessage.getData().keySet();
        for (Iterator<String> it = keySet.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            String keyValue = it.next();
            if (  keyValue.contains("message")){
                found=true;
                Log.e(TAG, "ChatLogicFunctionality starts "+keyValue);
                ChatLogicFunctionality();
            }
        }

        if(!found){
            Log.e(TAG, " unknown stuff ");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception "+e.getMessage());
    }



}
```

So the person sends for example every 2 seconds. It works for a while I see the logs in the onMessageReceived but then it just stops. Then it comes much later.

Does google block or something ? 
For chat realtime purpose what should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing testing so it maybe related to same .collapseKey("message") 
I will continue on testing if it fixes I will accept as answer.